# Retrieve list of General Ledger transaction lines without error itgenugs026

Tags: exact-online, invantive-sql, invantive-query-tool

When I run the following query on Exact Online, I receive an error itgenugs026: `The requested number of 1,396 columns is not supported.`

```
select *
from   GLTransactionLines  t
```

How can I get the list of general ledger transactions through the XML API?

The REST API TransactionLines with identical named table has the data, but the LineNumber column is currently empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tables for the XML API are a little hard to use. The XSD on start.exactonline.com lists all possibilities and even has recursion, so it is quite hard to determine which XML-attributes are actually returned and can be used in the query.

The grid used has a performance issue when there are tens of thousands columns displayed, so it has been topped off.

You can try to guess the column names. The error message might give you the actual name, since it tries to find similar column names that actually exist.

But the best way is to:

- First click in the Query Tool Results tab on the small button above the grid labeled "Hide empty columns" (it is the most right one, next to "Display Layout").
- Then run the query as `select * from XMLTABLE`.

The results grid then only shows columns that actually occur with a value in the XML API.

Note that per environment different fields with values can be returned in XML. For instance, only when you have a license on cost management, you will see values for Cost Center and Cost Unit.